# ggplot2, Annotate y axis to indicate direction of scale used

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have produced a bar graph with a (continuous) y axis that reflects perceptual lightness distortion. The way my data were measured, numbers above zero mean those objects were judged lighter than they actually are and numbers below zero mean those objects were judged darker than they actually are. How can I place some text next to the y axis indicating the direction of the scale I used, i.e. "darker - lighter"? I would still like to keep my current y axis label as "Lightness Distortion (gray levels)" but just add an annotation clarifying the scale to the reader.

Here is a sample of my data:

```
   "Subject"    "Cond"  "Distortion"
"1" "White" 10.7
"2" "White" 19.4
"3" "White" 15.9
"4" "White" 13.5
"5" "White" 15.4
"1" "Ambiguous" 13.4
"2" "Ambiguous" 11.4
"3" "Ambiguous" 8.9
"4" "Ambiguous" 11.0
"5" "Ambiguous" 11.4
"1" "Black" 8.4
"2" "Black" 1.7
"3" "Black" 7.7
"4" "Black" 8.0
"5" "Black" 5.7
```

And the code to produce my bar graph:

```
library(ggplot2)
g <- ggplot(data, aes(x = Cond, y = Distortion))
g + stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom="bar",position="dodge",
                 fill = "Gray",colour="Black") + 
        stat_summary(fun.data=mean_cl_normal, geom="errorbar",
                     position=position_dodge(width=0.90), width=0.2) +
        labs(x="Faces", y = "Lightness Distortion (gray levels)")+
        theme_bw()
```

[sample graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKEHZ.png)

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure of the look you're after, but this shows two ways to position text outside the plot panel. For both methods, the first task is to create a new text grob containing the text "Lighter" and "Darker". The first method positions the new grob using the `gtable` function, `gtable_add_grob`; the second method positions the grob using the `ggplot` function, `annotation_custom`.

```
# Your data
data = read.table(text = '  "Subject"    "Cond"  "Distortion"
"1" "White" 10.7
"2" "White" 19.4
"3" "White" 15.9
"4" "White" 13.5
"5" "White" 15.4
"1" "Ambiguous" 13.4
"2" "Ambiguous" 11.4
"3" "Ambiguous" 8.9
"4" "Ambiguous" 11.0
"5" "Ambiguous" 11.4
"1" "Black" 8.4
"2" "Black" 1.7
"3" "Black" 7.7
"4" "Black" 8.0
"5" "Black" 5.7', header = TRUE)

library(ggplot2)
library(gtable)
library(grid)

# The plot
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = Cond, y = Distortion)) +
     stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "bar", position = "dodge",
       fill = "Gray", colour = "black") + 
     stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_normal, geom = "errorbar",
       position = position_dodge(width = 0.90), width = 0.2) +
     labs(x = "Faces", y = "Lightness Distortion (gray levels)") +
     theme_bw()

## Using `gtable` to position the text grob 
# Set up text grob
text.grob1 <- textGrob("Darker", y = 0,  just = "left", 
   rot = 90, gp = gpar(fontsize = 10, col = "red", fontface = "italic"))

text.grob2 <- textGrob("Lighter", y = 1, just = "right", 
   rot = 90, gp = gpar(fontsize = 10, col = "red", fontface = "italic"))

# Combine them into a single grob
text.grob <- gTree(children = gList(text.grob1, text.grob2)) 

# Get ggplot grob
g <- ggplotGrob(p)

# Add the grob to the column containing the y axis title
pos = subset(g$layout, grepl("ylab-l", name), t:l)
g <- gtable_add_grob(g, text.grob, l = pos$l, t = pos$t)

# Draw it
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

[image]

```
## Using `annotation_custom` to position the text grob
# Set up text grob
text.grob1 <- textGrob("Lighter", y = 0, just = "left", 
   rot = 90, gp = gpar(fontsize = 10, col = "red", fontface = "italic"),
   vjust = -2.5)

text.grob2 <- textGrob("Darker", y = 1, just = "right", 
   rot = 90, gp = gpar(fontsize = 10, col = "red", fontface = "italic"),
   vjust = -2.5)

 # Combine them into a single grob
text.grob <- gTree(children = gList(text.grob1, text.grob2)) 

# Add the grob to the plot
p <- p + annotation_custom(text.grob, 
      xmin = -Inf, xmax = -Inf, ymin = Inf, ymax = -Inf) 

# The new grob is positioned outside the plot panel. 
# To see the grob, clipping needs to be turned off.
g = ggplotGrob(p)
g$layout$clip <- "off"

# Draw it
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

Comment: Thanks Sandy! I ended up using method #1 (gtable) but instead used a single text grob with the string "Darker - Lighter". I did a lot of "trial and error" tweaking to the y position argument to textGrob and eventually got the dash to line up nicely with the zero on the y axis. Thanks for all the useful information! Cheers